# Kafka Global Table not updating from source topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am creating a Springboot app and struggling to understand why my GlobalKtable is not updating.

As far as I understand, the global table is supposed to update automatically when the source topic is updated. This is not the case for me.

I did notice the global table becomes populated with new data after I manually delete the state store folder.

I also noted the following error output when the Spring boot app is launched:

> **2021-11-27 23:09:18.232 ERROR 17592 --- [           main] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory       : Failed to change
> permissions for the directory d:\kafkastreamsdb
>
> 2021-11-27 23:09:18.233 ERROR 17592 --- [           main]
> o.a.k.s.p.internals.StateDirectory       : Failed to change
> permissions for the directory d:\kafkastreamsdb\Kafka-streams**

Seems to me the reason why I only see all the current data in the GlobalKtable after deleting the statestore folder is because the stream is not writing to the state store while the stream is running, but recreates the state store from the source topic after deletion?

So, the issue here is when I try to use the global table as a look-up in the join below, the enriched stream returns NULL for the table values. However, when I delete the state store folder, and restart Springboot, the enriched stream does return the table values.
Just to clarify, new events are continuously sent to the source topic, but this data is only visible in the table after deletion.

Here is my code:

```
@Service
public class TopologyBuilder2 {


  public static Topology build() {

      StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

      // Register FakeAddress stream
        KStream<String, FakeAddress> streamFakeAddress =
                builder.stream("FakeAddress", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), JsonSerdes.FakeAddress()));


     GlobalKTable<String, Greetings> globalGreetingsTable = builder.globalTable(
               "Greetings"
               , Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), JsonSerdes.Greetings())
               , Materialized.<String, Greetings, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                       "GREETINGS" /* table/store name */)
                       .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()) /* key serde */
                        .withValueSerde(JsonSerdes.Greetings()) /* value serde */);


       // LEFT Key mapper
        KeyValueMapper<String, FakeAddress, String> keyMapperFakeAddress =
                ( leftkey, fakeAddress) -> {
                  //  System.out.println(String.valueOf(fakeAddress.getCountry()));
                    return String.valueOf(fakeAddress.getCountry());
                };

        // Value joiner
        ValueJoiner<FakeAddress, Greetings, EnrichedCountryGreeting> valueJoinerFakeAddressAndGreetings =
                (fakeAddress, greetings) -> new EnrichedCountryGreeting(fakeAddress, greetings);


      KStream<String, EnrichedCountryGreeting> enrichedStream
              = streamFakeAddress.join(globalGreetingsTable, keyMapperFakeAddress, valueJoinerFakeAddressAndGreetings);

      enrichedStream.print(Printed.<String, EnrichedCountryGreeting>toSysOut().withLabel("Stream-enrichedStream: "));


       return builder.build();


   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried modifying your directory permission `d:\kafkastreamsdb` to `"rwxr-x---"`? Is it successful or not? I simply think your app doesn't have enough privileges to do that. Or try to use another version of Kafka if https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/9947 was your problem.

Comment: Have you verified the .checkpoint file inside the data folder of your Kafka stream ? This file is inside <application id>/global/. It list down the last offset it has read from the global topic. There might be a timing issue if this file contains the latest offset number.

Comment: I tried another folder. Also tried switching from Windows to Linux to see if it was a compatibility issue. That error for internals.StateDirectory is now gone.  But still not reading the data correctly.
Inside .checkpoint looks like this:
0
3
Greetings 0 0
Greetings 1 0
Greetings 2 1

Comment: I finally got it working. Still don't know why it was not working, but the solution was here:

I changed the Serializer from CAMELCASE to IDENTITY, and that did the trick. Dont know why this works though.

    private Gson gson =new GsonBuilder()
            .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY)
            .create();